# How to list all S3 methods defined in a specific package / namespace for a particular generic function

Tags: r, function, methods

I know I can list all S3 methods for a particular generic function, say `summary`, by

```
.S3methods("summary")
# [1] summary.aov                    summary.aovlist*              
# [3] summary.aspell*                summary.check_packages_in_dir*
# [5] summary.connection             summary.data.frame            
# [7] summary.Date                   summary.default               
# [9] summary.ecdf*                  summary.factor                
#[11] summary.glm                    summary.infl*                 
#[13] summary.lm                     summary.loess*                
#[15] summary.manova                 summary.matrix                
#[17] summary.mlm*                   summary.nls*                  
#[19] summary.packageStatus*         summary.PDF_Dictionary*       
#[21] summary.PDF_Stream*            summary.POSIXct               
#[23] summary.POSIXlt                summary.ppr*                  
#[25] summary.prcomp*                summary.princomp*             
#[27] summary.proc_time              summary.srcfile               
#[29] summary.srcref                 summary.stepfun               
#[31] summary.stl*                   summary.table                 
#[33] summary.tukeysmooth*
```

However, I know that some of these functions come from `stats`, while some from `base`. If I load more packages into R this list can be much longer. I therefore want to restrict the search in a particular package / namespace, but I don't find a way to do this.

The manual of `?.S3methods` appears to be self-contradicted.

```
 .S3methods(generic.function, class, envir=parent.frame())

envir: the environment in which to look for the definition of the
       generic function, when the generic function is passed as a
       character string.
```

So I tried the following but still get all methods displayed:

```
.S3methods("summary", envir = getNamespace("base"))
```

In "Details" section of the manual, it is said:

> ‘methods()’ finds S3 and S4 methods associated with either the ’generic.function’ or ‘class’ argument. **Methods are found in all packages on the current ‘search()’ path.** ‘.S3methods()’ finds only S3 methods, ‘.S4methods()’ finds only only S4 methods.

So basically it denies the use of argument `envir`.

Is there anyway I can achieve a restricted search and display.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[MrFlick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51729406/4891738) (now unfortunately deleted) is very helpful. It is my fault to have forgotten to check the returned values of `.S3methods`. However, his answer does not completely resolve the matter.

```
xx <- .S3methods("summary")
yy <- attr(xx, "info")
levels(yy$from)
#[1] "base"                            "datasets"                       
#[3] ".GlobalEnv"                      "graphics"                       
#[5] "grDevices"                       "methods"                        
#[7] "stats"                           "utils"                          
#[9] "registered S3method for summary"
```

The level "registered S3method for summary" is rather ambiguous. With this approach, only 5 results from `stats` package can be displayed:

```
xx[yy$from == "stats"]
#[1] "summary.aov"     "summary.glm"     "summary.lm"      "summary.manova" 
#[5] "summary.stepfun"
```

Just after my posting this question, I realized that there is one way via *regex*. And this reveals that in fact there are 16 hits.

```
grep("^summary.", ls(getNamespace("stats")), value = TRUE)
# [1] "summary.aov"         "summary.aovlist"     "summary.ecdf"       
# [4] "summary.glm"         "summary.infl"        "summary.lm"         
# [7] "summary.loess"       "summary.manova"      "summary.mlm"        
#[10] "summary.nls"         "summary.ppr"         "summary.prcomp"     
#[13] "summary.princomp"    "summary.stepfun"     "summary.stl"        
#[16] "summary.tukeysmooth"
```

So before any alternative solution is found, I would stay with using *regex*. Here is a function.

```
## provide (generic) function name and package name as strings
findS3Fun <- function (Fun, pkg) {
  all_fun <- ls(getNamespace(pkg))
  all_fun[startsWith(all_fun, sprintf("%s.", Fun))]
  }

findS3Fun("summary", "stats")
```

---

#### ahem, *regex* is buggy!

`findS3Fun` is actually buggy.

```
findS3Fun("seq", "base")
#[1] "seq.Date"    "seq.default" "seq.int"     "seq.POSIXt" 

findS3Fun("sort", "base")
#[1] "sort.default" "sort.int"     "sort.list"    "sort.POSIXlt"
```

`seq.int` is not the "int" method for `seq`. Neither `sort.int` nor `sort.list` is the "int" or "list" method for `sort`. They are just stand alone functions with `.` in their function name.

```
.S3methods("seq")
#[1] seq.Date    seq.default seq.POSIXt 

.S3methods("sort")
#[1] sort.bibentry* sort.default   sort.POSIXlt 

## this function is from package `utils` not `base`
environment(getS3method("sort", "bibentry"))
#<environment: namespace:utils>
```

So the safest approach is probably still to work with the returned values of `.S3methods`.

#### use `getAnywhere` (`getS3method`)

Back to the example with "summary". Functions that are not exported from namespaces, i.e., those with `yy$visible = FALSE`, have `yy$from = "registered S3method for summary"`.

```
with(yy, from[!visible])
# [1] registered S3method for summary registered S3method for summary
# [3] registered S3method for summary registered S3method for summary
# [5] registered S3method for summary registered S3method for summary
# [7] registered S3method for summary registered S3method for summary
# [9] registered S3method for summary registered S3method for summary
#[11] registered S3method for summary registered S3method for summary
#[13] registered S3method for summary registered S3method for summary
#[15] registered S3method for summary registered S3method for summary
#8 Levels: base datasets graphics grDevices methods stats ... registered S3method for summary
```

However, since we know the names of these functions, why not apply `getAnywhere` on them?

```
zz <- lapply(xx[!yy$visible], getAnywhere)
```

Then the package / namespace information can be extracted from `zz` with some effort. However, this `lapply` + `getAnywhere` is quite slow. Since `getAnywhere` returns more things than I needed, I dug into its source code to see whether I could do some trimming. It turns out that I can.

```
hidden <- xx[!yy$visible]
# [1] "summary.aovlist"               "summary.aspell"               
# [3] "summary.check_packages_in_dir" "summary.ecdf"                 
# [5] "summary.infl"                  "summary.loess"                
# [7] "summary.mlm"                   "summary.nls"                  
# [9] "summary.packageStatus"         "summary.PDF_Dictionary"       
#[11] "summary.PDF_Stream"            "summary.ppr"                  
#[13] "summary.prcomp"                "summary.princomp"             
#[15] "summary.stl"                   "summary.tukeysmooth"  

CLASS <- substr(hidden, nchar("summary") + 2L, nchar(hidden))
#[1] "aovlist"               "aspell"                "check_packages_in_dir"
# [4] "ecdf"                  "infl"                  "loess"                
# [7] "mlm"                   "nls"                   "packageStatus"        
#[10] "PDF_Dictionary"        "PDF_Stream"            "ppr"                  
#[13] "prcomp"                "princomp"              "stl"                  
#[16] "tukeysmooth"          

vapply(CLASS,
       function (u) getNamespaceName(environment(getS3method("summary", u)))[[1L]],
       "", USE.NAMES = FALSE)
# [1] "stats" "utils" "tools" "stats" "stats" "stats" "stats" "stats" "utils"
#[10] "tools" "tools" "stats" "stats" "stats" "stats" "stats"
```

#### Final solution

Now let me wrap up these ideas into a function.

```
findS3Fun <- function (Fun, pkg) {
  xx <- .S3methods(Fun)
  yy <- attr(xx, "info")[1:2]
  where <- yy[[2L]]  ## yy$from
  where <- levels(where)[where]  ## factor to character
  hidden <- !yy[[1L]]  ## !yy$visible
  hidden_xx <- xx[hidden]  ## hidden functions
  if (length(hidden) > 0L) {
    CLASS <- substr(hidden_xx, nchar(Fun) + 2L, nchar(hidden_xx))
    aux <- function (u) getNamespaceName(environment(getS3method(Fun, u)))[[1L]]
    where[hidden] <- vapply(CLASS, aux, "", USE.NAMES = FALSE)
    }
  export <- where == pkg
  xx <- xx[export]
  visible <- yy[[1L]][export]
  ## use "regex" to find functions with "." in their names but not methods
  all_fun <- ls(getNamespace(pkg))
  all_fun <- all_fun[startsWith(all_fun, sprintf("%s.", Fun))]
  misc <- all_fun[!(all_fun %in% xx)]
  ## return functions by category
  list(visible = xx[visible], invisible = xx[!visible], misc = misc)
  }
```

In the end I still use *regex* to catch functions with `.` in their names but are not rightful methods. They are classified as "misc", besides "visible" and "invisible".

#### Test

```
findS3Fun("summary", "stats")
#$visible
#[1] "summary.aov"     "summary.glm"     "summary.lm"      "summary.manova" 
#[5] "summary.stepfun"
#
#$invisible
# [1] "summary.aovlist"     "summary.ecdf"        "summary.infl"       
# [4] "summary.loess"       "summary.mlm"         "summary.nls"        
# [7] "summary.ppr"         "summary.prcomp"      "summary.princomp"   
#[10] "summary.stl"         "summary.tukeysmooth"
#
#$misc
#character(0)
```

```
findS3Fun("sort", "base")
#$visible
#[1] "sort.default" "sort.POSIXlt"
#
#$invisible
#character(0)
#
#$misc
#[1] "sort.int"  "sort.list"
```

```
findS3Fun("[", "base")
#$visible
# [1] "[.AsIs"            "[.data.frame"      "[.Date"           
# [4] "[.difftime"        "[.Dlist"           "[.factor"         
# [7] "[.hexmode"         "[.listof"          "[.noquote"        
#[10] "[.numeric_version" "[.octmode"         "[.POSIXct"        
#[13] "[.POSIXlt"         "[.simple.list"     "[.table"          
#[16] "[.warnings"       
#
#$invisible
#character(0)
#
#$misc
#character(0)
```

```
findS3Fun("[[", "base")
#$visible
#[1] "[[.data.frame"      "[[.Date"            "[[.factor"         
#[4] "[[.numeric_version" "[[.POSIXct"        
#
#$invisible
#character(0)
#
#$misc
#character(0)
```

Comment: For robustness, I should probably do some input validation. For example: `if (!(pkg %in% .packages())) stop(sprintf("package '%s' has not been loaded with 'library(%s)'!", pkg, pkg))`; But checking whether `Fun` is a S3 generic is difficult. `isS3stdGeneric` is not able to catch all of them, say, `sort`.